# Getting null response when trying to call makeEwsRequestAsync()

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have built an Outlook Web Addin using Office-JS API. The addin has been tested from various endpoints and I know it works. However on some other machines I received a `null` response from the Exchange2013 server when trying to call `mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync`. The operation is of type `GetItem`

Here is my **XML SOAP**:

```xml
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header> 
        <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" /> 
    </soap:Header> 
    <soap:Body>
        <m:GetItem> 
            <m:ItemShape> 
                <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape> 
                <t:IncludeMimeContent>true</t:IncludeMimeContent> 
                <t:AdditionalProperties> 
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:InternetMessageHeaders" />
                </t:AdditionalProperties>
            </m:ItemShape> 
            <m:ItemIds>
                <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGFhOWQ3MWI0LWI3OWMtNDUyNy1iN2VhLTk5ZTg3N2UwMzc3OABGAAAAAACRYBMGwHc0T5HJQ/j+HHxaBwC8uj9oQcTXT4ysVvJ0+bvCAAAAU7w5AADOMEgE+yLSTL4F+7TbwddyAAMnU1GOAAA="/> 
            </m:ItemIds>
        </m:GetItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Why am I getting null reponse from server ?

**UPDATE**
This is the last response I got:

```
{"Body":null,"ErrorMessage":"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.","StatusCode":0,"StatusDescription":null,"WasProxySuccessful":false}
```

Comment: A few clarifying questions: What platforms is this occurring on (Mac/Windows/OWA/Android/iOS?) What do you mean by a `null` response? Is `result.value` null or does EWS return a null response? If the latter, could you share what that response looks like? In either case, are you sure that you are requesting a valid item for the given user? What is your add-in's permission level?

Comment: Ok so I think I have figure out what the problem is. My client is using a proxy configuration (which I don't have access to) and the proxy blocks the ```makeEwsRequestAsync``` call. How can I instruct the ```OfficeJS``` to use the default proxy ?

Comment: I have also updated answer

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to bypass the client's proxy, or use it? Also, it sounds like your customer is on-premise. Is this correct? If so, what platforms do they use (web/desktop/mobile/ect)?

Comment: The client is using the proxy. We are trying to make this compatible with his proxy (so use it to answer the question). The platform is Windows and it has been tested on Web (OWA). Yes they are using on-premise

Comment: When you make an EWS request in OWA, the payload is returned to the server hosting OWA (your client's server in this case) and sent from there (which is usually just a loopback, as the OWA Server and Exchange Server are usually the same machine) so if you're getting a 404, it may be an issue in the configuration of your client's Exchange Server.

Comment: Do you have any idea what could be the cause ? (what config could be wrong ?)

Comment: It may help to try to capture the failure from the back-end where the user's mailbox is active, using IIS FailedRequestTracing, and can try to isolate to HTTP Status Code 404 responses on the EWS virtual directory on the "Exchange Back End" website.  This is based on a few assumptions - presumes that the request did actually get to the back-end as an OWA request, and then unpacked and re-issued as an EWS request which ultimately failed with 404 response.  When looking at the error response, look at the whole response, in case there are response headers that carry additional useful details.